# Call Recording in Freeswitch

Tags: freeswitch

I have a freeswitch working on one server and call is working fine.
But now i want to record each and every call to some specific format like .wav OR .gsm
I already tried with "record_session" application.[Record session application](https://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Misc._Dialplan_Tools_record_session)

Is it right application for record call ?

If yes then please suggest me to some example and if not then suggest me other application also.

Answer (score 9):

This question is old but I'll still answer it for the people who could benefit in future.

`record_session` will record the entire session including the ringing. If you just want to record the conversation use `execute_on_answer=record_session` followed by complete file path, like so:

```
<action application="export" data="execute_on_answer=record_session $${base_dir}/recordings/${strftime(%Y%m%d%H%M%S)}_${caller_id_number}.wav"/>
```

Comment: It's an old thread, I have a tangential question, maybe it will get answered: what do I need to to (or search for) to create an application which would record a call on freeswitch?

Answer (score 2):

You can record a call by adding the command below into the dialplan:

```
<action application="record" data="/tmp/data.wav 20 200"/>
```

The format of this is `record,Record File,<path> [<time_limit_secs>] [<silence_thresh>] [<silence_hits>]` with `time_limit_secs`, `silence_thresh`, `silence_hits` all being optional.

Refer the FreeSWITCH wiki for more details.

https://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Misc._Dialplan_Tools_record

EDIT: As @hdiogenes pointed out, this records like a voicemail. What you OP is looking for is the application record_session.

https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/record_session

Comment: This is not the right application. He wants to record two-legged calls, and the "record" application will record only one leg, like in a voicemail system.

Comment: The documentation for record_session has moved: https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/mod_dptools%3A+record_session

Comment: Sample usage: `<action application="record_session" data="$${base_dir}/recordings/${strftime(%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S)}_${destination_number}_${caller_id_number}.wav"/>`