# Recording Call streams separately in FreeSWITCH

Tags: freeswitch

I am running a FreeSWITCH server that will function as a call-in radio show. What I want to do is create a platform that will enable the user to edit the show in post-production, which includes creating a custom show/object using the recorded audio.

How I want to do this is record each leg of the call separately, so that way I can record the host separately to the listener calling in. Is this recording action available in FreeSWITCH?

This Question on SO is related:
[Call Recording in Freeswitch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26313201/call-recording-in-freeswitch)

and one of the answers mentions the

which according to the official [wiki](https://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Misc._Dialplan_Tools_record) "is used for recording messages, like in a voicemail system".

The question is, Am I able to invoke this record action on both legs of the call? Or any equivalents that exist within FreeSWITCH?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you set the variable `RECORD_STEREO=true` and use a `FILENAME.wav` file as recording destination, the resulting file will have two audio channels, for receiving and sending sides respectively. Then later you can split the channels by your favorite audio editing tool and do what is needed.

Comment: I had considered this, but I was looking for a 'Live' solution.. Something that didn't require tinkering in post-production. Such a solution would be the holy grail!

If this is not possible, then in post-production, can either split the channels or use a timestamp based approach to split audio files into relevant clips... But preferably, both of these solutions would be Plan B...

Comment: if you don't specify the file extension, then FreeSWITCH will record two files, one for sending and the other for receiving sides. But the resulting files will be in raw codec that is actually selected for the channel, so you will need to take the codec into consideration when reading those files. I think it's a way more complex way than just splitting the stereo files. You can trigger the splitting right after the end of recording, there's a variable for launching an app automatically when the recording finishes.

Comment: actually if you record the call-in session, you will get a separate recording for each guest. But you can also record the host's session, and that will give you the whole show recorded in one file, with one channel representing the host and the other with guests. Then you would only need to cut off unneeded parts in post-production

Comment: thanks for that, very helpful. If i called the host and the guests from the server (this is to add resilience so that even if internet connectivity of host is gone, still will be able to carry on a conference call style show), will this then generate a separate recording for each guest (and host) in the show?

Comment: depends how you organize your calls. If you do it from mod_conference, then the whole session will be recorded in one file

Comment: I know it is beyond the scope of the question but if I wanted to have separate recordings, does FreeSWITCH support calling a bunch of numbers without using mod_conference, i.e. is there an alternate way of recording callers separately?

Comment: Yes, there's a variable to disable hangup after bridge. Then the host session stays when the guest hangs up.

Comment: you can easily find me in skype and google hangouts, so we can move the discussion there.